# Visual Studio 2022 not building when source files changed

Tags: visual-studio, build

Using Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.8.3 to build a MAUI project.

VS is not building projects after changing source files - I have do a clean, exit VS, delete bin and obj folders and restart VS.

I have set 'Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run' unchecked in options.

I have also set 'On Run, when projects are out of date' to 'Prompt to build' - I never get a prompt.

Another observation - if I just do a clean of the solution, I get the error that the Android dll in the obj folder cannot be found.

This has just started occurring on a solution for which VS was previously detecting source file changes and building as appropriate.

I also have another solution which builds properly (i.e. builds appropriate projects if a source file is changed) on the same computer. So something solution-related?

This is making development very inefficient! Any thoughts?